# Power of mixed effects model vs ANOVA repeated measures within-between interaction

Tags: statistical-power, gpower

I'm trying to estimate the power of a 3X3 longitudinal mixed effects model with 3 groups, 3 measurement timepoints, and participant ID as a random intercept.

I know that using the "ANOVA repeated measures within-between interaction" design (as shown below) isn't exactly right, but I'm wondering how close it is to the proper mixed effects model power. Also, would the power of a mixed effects model always be higher than that of an ANOVA in this case?

[image: between-within ANOVA in G*Power]

Comment: What is the duration of follow-up?  How do you know that the serial correlation structure that is probably present is adequately handled by either method, since neither was designed for serial correlation patterns but instead for exchangeable measurements within subject?  See https://fharrell.com/post/re